# Is there a discrete version of the exponential distribution?

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution, discrete-data

The exponential distribution is well-known and widely used but defined for a continuous variable. Is there a discrete version of it?

Comment: That'd be the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).